# Using d3.csv to read key value pair

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, dataframe

Looking to make a map visualization. Wanted a simple key-value object in this format:

```
 {
      Alabama: "AL",
      Alaska: "AK",
      Arizona: "AZ",
      ...
 }
```

Read data as such:

```js
    var source = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv";
    
    var stateCodes = {};
    
    d3.csv(source, data => {
        data.map(d => {
            stateCodes[d["state"]] = d["code"];
            return stateCodes;   
        }); 
    });

    console.log(stateCodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Try to run this snippet. It seems to be grabbing the right data points but not populating the `stateCodes` object or not returning it.

What should I change?

Comment: Am I missing something? `stateCodes` seems populated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your `console.log` after `d3.csv` method which is asynchronous. Move it after `d3.map` and check that `stateCodes` was populated:

[Docs for `d3.csv` method](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv).

```js
var source = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv";
    
var stateCodes = {};
    
d3.csv(source, (data) => {
    data.map(d => {
        stateCodes[d["state"]] = d["code"];
        return stateCodes;   
    });
 
    console.log(stateCodes);
    // other code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Pay attention that in your data file `California` has a space character at the beginning.

[image]

You can fix it in source file or use `trim` method:

`stateCodes[d["state"].trim()] = d["code"];`;